# How to detect a transaction that will fail in web3js

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I've just recently finished working on a rather complex contract with the Remix IDE.  I'm now attaching web3 to the frontend but when I call functions that should fail, they still go through on Metamask.

When testing my contract in Remix, I would often click on and call certain functions that had require statements that I knew would fail just to confirm that the contract state was recorded correctly.  Remix didn't send the transaction to metamask and instead output an error message and I would like to handle the transaction error on my own as well.

How can I check my contract call to see whether it will fail.  Must I use the method that predicts gas and detect it that way and if so how?  My current code is below:

```
contract.callFunction(function(error, result) {
    if (!error) alert(result);
    else alert(error);
}
```

The above code catches rejecting the metamask confirmation as an error but transactions that should fail go through to metamask with an insanely high gas limit set.  The function callFunction is in the contract and takes no parameters but does have an effect on the blockchain so it requires the transaction.  The first line of the function is "require(state == 1);" and I have the contract set to state 2 currently so I'm expecting the transaction to fail, I just want to detect it failing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to find out whether the transaction will fail we do have to call estimateGas() and attach a callback function.  I assumed we'd have to check the gas estimate returned in order to predict whether it would fail but the process is made rather easy.  Here's the full code I ended up with to successfully run a function while catching the two most common error cases.

```
    contract.nextState.estimateGas(function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
            contract.nextState(function(error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    alert("This is my value: " + result);
                } else {
                    if (error.message.indexOf("User denied") != -1) {
                        alert("You rejected the transaction on Metamask!");
                    } else {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This function cannot be run at this time.");
        }
    });
```

[EDIT] I'm coming back after the fact to help clear up information for those with a similar question.  All of the information discussed below references the following [link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas).

After creating a contract object, you can access any variable or function through using it's name.  You can also access these members through array notation which is useful when the name of the variable or function isn't known at the time the code is written.

```
contract.foobar == contract["foobar"]
```

Once you have a function object (contract.foobar) you can use either call, send, or estimateGas.  After first giving the function the parameters it needs (call it like any other function) you then use either call, send, or estimateGas on the returned object while providing **options** and a **callback function**.

This callback function takes 2 parameters.  The first is the error which will be undefined if there was no error, and the second will be the result of the call, send, or estimateGas.  Call and Send will both return the result of the function while estimateGas always returns a number showing how much gas is estimated to be necessary.

Comment: It would be nice if you described a bit more what does the code do. Does `error !== undefined` mean that there would be an error in the transaction?

Comment: @NicSzer I hope you figured out the solution to your issue, and if you didn't hopefully my edit to the answer helps.  I love that (most likely) google led you to my question, and I personally hate finding a question on google that doesn't answer my question thoroughly so I apologize for the lack of information.

You are correct in that error being undefined means there was not an error.  If error is not undefined then it is the object containing the error information.

Comment: I am using web3 2.x (because Metamask injects this by default). It doesnt seem to have the .methods . Any idea how do I predict whether a call would fail?

Comment: Hey @Amarsh , afaik the changes to Metamask haven't changed what is being injected (just that it's now not automatically injected) and I can't find any documentation that says web3 is on 2.x.  Also, I didn't use ".methods" at all in my answer, this was deprecated long ago afaik and you instead access the function directly from the contract object.  Lmk if I can help further.

Comment: Hi, this solution works if you use MetaMask or Ethereum node, but it will not work with Infura service. Just FYI.

Comment: @VanjaDev Metamask uses Infura for it's node, so I imagine you're just trying to use the Infura service too directly.